# cdkStepLabel - ng-template - innerHTML

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-material-stepper

I am creating custom stepper using CDKStepper in angular 7,

I am using

```
<cdk-step>
      <ng-template cdkStepLabel>Fill out your name 1</ng-template>
      <p>This is any content of "Step 1"</p>
</cdk-step>
```

and in stepper template - for navigation, I am using

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills wizard-navigation-ul">
      <li class="step" *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIndex === i}">
          <a href="javascript:void()" (click)="onClick(i, step)" data-toggle="tab">{{step.stepLabel}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

and in Component.ts

```
onClick(index: number, step: any): void {
    console.log(step);   // here i want to console the title of the step clicked, in this case TEXT of this "<ng-template cdkStepLabel>Fill out your name 1</ng-template>"
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }
```

How can I get the title that is stored in `<ng-template cdkStepLabel>Fill out your name 1</ng-template>`?

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz/jsfiddle?

Comment: you can take this exact example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/yodnynygpev?file=app%2Fcdk-custom-stepper-without-form-example.ts   and in navigation where `step 1` and `step 2` are shown, I have to show the step name

Comment: rest is the same, except i added `<ng-template>` in `<cdk-step>` . like this ```<cdk-step>
      <ng-template cdkStepLabel>Fill out your name 1</ng-template>
      <p>This is any content of "Step 1"</p>
</cdk-step>```

Comment: <cdk-step label="Step 1"></cdk-step> Using label I'm getting step  label value but  using CdkStepLabel not getting the inner html value.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this and had to dig into the source code for a solution.

The `CdkStepLabel` directive has the `TemplateRef` as public.
Therefore we can do the following within our `CdkStepper` child component:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected.stepLabel.template"></ng-container>
```

(however you want to acces the correct step is up to you)

Hope this helps future searchers.